# Polymer dom-repeat xlink not rendered as expected

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, polymer, xlink

I have almost the same issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33146886/polymer-1-0-dynamic-use-xlinkhref-inside-template-not-working-properly) question describes.

I have some svg symbols which I want to dynamically insert with Polymers `dom-repeat`.

I get with a function all ids from the symbols I need in an array `{{icons}}` and I then loop true it to insert my svg's.

My code looks like this:

```
<div class = 'housing-icons'>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{icons}}">
    <div id = 'BUTTONID'>
      <svg class="icon">
        <use xlink:href$='{{item.id}}'></use>
        <!--<use xlink:href='#bed'></use>-->  !!! This works as expected !!!
      </svg>
    </div>
    <paper-tooltip class="tooltip" for="BUTTONID" animation-config="{"entry": [], "exit": []}" position="top"><div class="tooltip__label">Lorem ipsum</div></paper-tooltip>
  </template>
</div>
```

When I hard code the id `#bed` in the `<use>` tag everything is fine and looks like this in the dev tools:

```
<use xlink:href="#bed" class="style-scope custom-housing_icons"></use>
```

But when I want to use data-binding `{{item.id}}`, the icons are not shown and it looks like this in the dev tools:

```
<use class="style-scope custom-housing_icons" xlink:href="#bed"></use>
```

Any ideas how to solve this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is a know issue. There should also be another SO question. 
AFAIR a workaround is to add the namespace statically

```
<use xlink:href$='{{item.id}}' xlink:href='#dummy'></use>
```

Polymer seems to be able to update `xlink:href` just fine but can't create it.